# Adding a surrogate key to fact tables?

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to check if this is a logical set up. I am new to databases in general but I want to save some space and be efficient.

A daily snapshot of employees is being generated (50,000+ rows per day with over 70 columns). I am only interested in when changes happen so I drop duplicates and then add a column for `effective_date` and `expiration_date` along with `is_current`. Each time a dimension that I am tracking changes, I add a new row for that employee.

There are a lot of files being generated which consist of daily facts about these employees. Each of the files have the `employee_id` and the `date` which also exists on the daily employee snapshot file.

I was thinking of adding an integer key on the snapshot file (incrementing) and then looking up that integer and adding it to the fact table (I would be doing this with pandas/python during an ETL set up) before inserting the data into a database.

daily snapshot:

```
employee_integer_key | effective_date | employee_id | all employee info... |
            86            2016-01-06      abc123            stuff
```

a fact file:

```
date | employee_id | facts... |
```

I would then merge the tables based on the date and `employee_id` columns and only replace the `employee_id` column with the `employee_integer_key`.

a fact file:

```
date | employee_integer_key | facts... |
```

This integer should reflect a certain employee on a certain date when I join it with the daily snapshot file (between the effective and expiration dates). Is this a decent approach or should I try something else?

Comment: What actually changes? The snapped data? Either go the programmatic way by creating your own change history table as you do your updates or direct updates on the table with an update trigger. What you will care most about is the live data, why not split the changes and the current data? Warehousing changes + live data for extensive queries can be beneficial. By definition, surrogate keys are human comprehensible (your employee_id), what you're looking at is an identity column.

Comment: There are about 70 columns describing the employee. Which project they are on, which location, who they report to etc. (This information is provided in a daily .csv file from a third party, so it is a denormalized snapshot from a larger database which we have no access to). I keep track of 'important' changes in about 20 columns. If one of those dimensions changes I add a new row (I do the comparisons to old data in python, prior to inserting anything into the database). I need to be able to know, accurately, what a person's status was on a certain date (who was their manager, etc).

Comment: If that's what your setup looks like, since your search criteria are only based on a date and a specific employee, you can keep it all in a single table containing all of your fields.    Select * from emptable where effective_date < dateSearched and expiry_date > dateSearched and employee_id = empSearched.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid complicating your approach. KISS approach.
You are provided with a fresh csv file upon changes occurring. Simply do an insert into for everything found in there. Have your SQL table have an identity column and all columns found on that csv.

Actually, instead, I would use the "Import and Export Data" tool provided by SQL server so you can match your csv file's columns to your table(s). 
When searching for something relative to a date and/or employee:

`SELECT * FROM Emp_table 
WHERE effective_date < @dateSearched
AND expiry_date > @dateSearched
AND employee_id = @employeeSearched`

You want to have an identity column to help with the indexing. Sure, that table will be having a lot of lines, but it's nothing that can't be handled by SQL server.

Finally, if you are concerned with duplicates (completely identical rows - minus the identify column of course), please look into how to remove duplicates in SQL server. This kb article is ideal: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/139444

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, I am creating the csv to tell of changes occur. There is no indication on the original file, there is no effective or expiration date either. The providers of that information completely overwrite the same file each day so I save it and then combine the daily snapshots into something where I can see changes. But basically it sounds like I can just keep the date and employee ID and not worry about an integer key.

Comment: Yes, you don't need a surrogate key (in fact, you already have it as empId). Keep an identity field in your table for proper indexing though. If you're simply doing an insert, do you know how to go around to get the information you need? A CTE grouping on the employee id and returning only the top 1 for each employee would probably be the way to go.